Hovering the pointer to get information about reviewers doesn't work as before
Until yesterday, if I was visiting the review queues of some Stack Exchange site and my mouse pointer was hovering over the icon of some user, I would get information about the reviews of that user: the total number of reviews (within a given category) that that user made, as well as how many review that user made on that day, on the last week and on the last month, as in the image below.
But today things are different. If I put the pointer over an icon, the pointer turns into a hand (as it used to) which blinks, and that's all; the information mentioned above does not appear, until I move the pointer a little.
When the hand turns into a pointer, then, yes, that information appears. I suppose that this is a bug. 

Related / possibly same underlying issue: Usercard expansion does not work

And also: Catch them if you can... but you can't. (aka can't click "Watch tag" and "Ignore tag" from tag popup)

Same issue as this one. Fix is on its way. Sorry for the inconvenience, folks!
